# Complaint: A moderator closed my question despite other users clearly showing interest

Tags: discussion

A moderator recently closed my question, 2 years after it has been posted, despite having several replies and comments and a lot of upvotes from people.

Clearly my question is useful to lots of other people and there were active discussions on it:

[Replacement for Facebook Chat API in v2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988889/replacement-for-facebook-chat-api-in-v2-0)

Obviously I have no other way to dispute the moderator's decision than to post here. I am certain there are other threads on stackoverflow that are in bigger need of moderation (and closure) than my question here, so I am very puzzled and disappointed by [meagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/229044/meagar)'s action.

Comment: You can read the tip below _"Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: `I am certain there are other threads on stackoverflow that are in bigger need of moderation (and closure) than my question here` By that logic, you could never enforce *any* rule anywhere, because there’s other situations that need enforcing more

Comment: I have clearly marked the accepted answer for me but there are also a lot of  comments are useful input on the question. None of the comments look like spam, so this "reason" for closing my question is more of an excuse.

Comment: You misunderstand. The site generally prohibits that *category* of question because it often leads to spam and such, regardless of whether a specific question of that category has those problems or not. The rule would be impossible to enforce otherwise. Popularity does not count in deciding whether a question is off-topic or not. It’s a rule that is frequently disputed (I myself would prefer to see it changed) but it’s the way it is

Comment: It is funny how this community works: I now started getting lots of downvotes on my question :-) Looks like some people have too much time on their hands.

Comment: @NikolaySpassov by posting a direct link to the content you made it zero-effort for people to find it and do their Stack Overflow given and encouraged freedom to anonymously rate content. Its simple cause and effect, nothing more.

Comment: @NikolaySpassov: you would help your case much more by keeping the discussion on-topic and not cast aspersions on the motivations of voters or the moderator. Also, the elected moderators are here to do a job; in this case the moderator was cleaning up a series of flags and posts that yours was only tangentially involved with. They **were** doing a larger job.

Comment: You seem to have plenty of time quibbling about it here. So we're just keeping you entertained.

Comment: High odds that the moderator got annoyed with the busywork of maintaining the Q+A.  Triggered by a now deleted answer posted the day before that was quite spammy and surely was attracting flags.  Recommendation questions are a powerful spam magnet, basic reason why there is a dedicated close reason for them.

Comment: @NikolaySpassov so, the DVs you see on your question is a direct consequence of "the meta effect". Basically meta is visited by the most quality minded memberd of the community. You cast a spotlight on your question, which is off-topic. No surprise there is an increased amount of votes on your question.

Comment: I guess you'll just have to... deal with it.  Many anger.  Very sorrow.

Answer (score 21):

I can't necessarily speak to the moderator's mindset when they closed this question, but here's what I see.

This is a question which is fairly old and asks the premise, "what other alternative API can I use?"  At the strictest letter of the law, this is indeed asking for an off-site resource (i.e. another API to replace/supplant the now defunct Facebook API you were using), so it'd be fair game to be closed in my mind.

It doesn't matter if there are "active discussions" as you put it; a question can have lots of activity and still be eligible to be closed.

It also might interest you to know that, [according to the post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/23988889/timeline), it did make its way through the review queue and three people decided to vote to leave it closed.  If you can genuinely reform the question into one which doesn't involve asking for a replacement API, you can do so again and try once more with the review queues.